# ggplot2: Problems with creating a map with filled regions and filled points (shape 21)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I can create a map with filled regions and coloured points when I use shape 16 for the points, but something goes wrong when I using shape 21 and try to fill the points based on wich category they belong to.

Reproducible example (partly taken from the ggplot documentation):

```
ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))

values <- data.frame(
id = ids,
value = c(3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.15, 3.5)
)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3,
        0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
  y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5,
        2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2)
)

points <- data.frame(
  xpos = c(0.7, 1.5),
  ypos = c(1, 2.5),
  category = c("A", "B")
)
```

This works:

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_map(data = values, aes(map_id = id, fill = value), colour =  "darkgrey",
            map = positions) + 
  expand_limits(positions) +
  coord_equal() +
  geom_point(data=points, aes(x=xpos, y=xpos, colour = category),
         size=5, shape=16)
```

When I try to map category to a filled point (shape 21) it fails with 
"Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale":

```
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = values, aes(map_id = id, fill = value), map =     positions) +
  expand_limits(positions) +
  coord_equal() +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, fill = category), 
         shape = 21, colour = "black", size=5)
```

But it works if I map the category variable to colour instead of fill:

```
  ggplot() +
      geom_map(data = values, aes(map_id = id, fill = value), map = positions) +
      expand_limits(positions) +
      coord_equal() +
      geom_point(data = points, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, colour = category), 
         shape = 21, fill = "black", size=5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well I guess you set up a continous scale for fill with `geom_map`. That doesn't match with the class of `category`. Maybe you could use `as.numeric(category)`.

Comment: Thank! It works if I use. fill = as.numeric(category), but then I have to use a continues colour scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lukeA`'s answer is good if you can or want to rely on the auto-scaling. If you don't want to rely on the auto-scaling of the colors, you can also pass in a vector of colors to `fill` outside of `aes` that map to the points:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = values, aes(map_id = id, fill = value), map =     positions) +
  expand_limits(positions) +
  coord_equal() +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos), fill=I(c("red", "green")), 
         shape = 21, colour = "black", size=5)
```

[image]

It does mean some manual work, but it will give you different colors from the already-used scaled ones.

You'll need to deal with making a legend on your own (possibly easiest with `gridExtra`) but you get great control over colors.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I have hundreds of point. Even If it isn't a lot of work to match every point to a colour, it would be much easier if I somhow could override the linking of fill to a continous variable. (edited)

Comment: then don't use a continuous fill for the map polygons